# Firebase - Adding a TXT Record to Connect Custom Domain in Dynadot

Tags: firebase, dns, cname, firebase-hosting

I purchased my domain at Dynadot and now I need to connect that to my Firebase Web App.

Firebase requires me to add 2 TXT values to my domain registrar's DNS settings

[image]

However, Dynadot requires me to add A/AAAA/CNAME along with the TXT records. It gives me this error:

[image]

This is what my DNS looks like:

[image]

What am I missing here? Where can I find the information required for A or CNAME records in firebase?

Answer (score 2):

Firebase Hosting uses a two-step process for setting up your domain:

1. verify that you own the domain using two TXT records
2. set up the A, AAAA and CNAME records to forward traffic to Firebase Hosting

Firebase Hosting will not send you the details for step 2 until you've completed step 1.

If your provider doesn't allow you to enter TXT records without entering A and AAAA records, you can enter dummy values for step 1 and edit them once you get the values from Firebase in step 2.

Comment: What kind of dummy values?

Comment: Since they're *dummy* values (you'll replace them with the *actual* values at the next step), it doesn't really matter what you put in there as long as dynadot considers it valid.

Comment: Problem with that process is, Firebase detects this and gives me an error 'Invalid TXT records found'